# MySQL user defined function in shell script

Tags: mysql, function, shell, sh

I'm running this shell script:

```
root@user:/#sh myscript.sh
```

It contains the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
mysql -u username -password base1 << EOF
UPDATE table1 SET `trans` = translit (dn);
```

On the output, I get error against the line with my user defined function `translit`. All other MySQL commands are completed successfully. Under phpMyAdmin, the mentioned command runs correctly. Function `translit` is properly defined.

Comment: Try: `UPDATE table1 SET \`trans\` = translit(dn);`. See [9.2.4 Function Name Parsing and Resolution](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/function-resolution.html).

Comment: Just tried.. nope ( ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 23: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= translit(dn)' at line 1

Comment: works this way UPDATE table1 SET table1.trans=translit(table1.dn);

Comment: Is you shell script interpreting the back-quotes as command substitution?

Answer (score 0):

The backquotes in the here document are interpreted as a command substitution and processed by the shell before `mysql` runs. Quote the delimiter to protect the contents of the here document from shell processing.

```
#!/bin/bash -x
mysql -u username -password base1 << 'EOF'
UPDATE table1 SET `trans` = translit (dn);
EOF
```

(Note: I'm not familiar enough with MySQL to know if the backquotes should actually be single quotes or not, or if any quoting is necessary here.)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

File: `myscript.sh`

```bsh
#!/bin/bash -x
mysql -u username -p -s << 'EOF'
USE `base1`;
SELECT `dn`, `trans` 
FROM `table1`;

UPDATE `table1`
SET `trans` = `translit`(`dn`);

SELECT CONCAT(REPEAT('*', 15), ' UPDATE ', REPEAT('*', 15));

SELECT `dn`, `trans`
FROM `table1`;
EOF
```

```sql
$ mysql -u username -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 1
Server version: 5.7.11

Copyright (c) 2000, 2016, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `base1`;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `base1`;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> USE `base1`;
Database changed

mysql> DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `translit`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table1`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table1` (
    ->   `dn` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    ->   `trans` VARCHAR(30)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `table1`
    ->   (`dn`)
    -> VALUES
    ->   ('Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy'),
    ->   ('text of the printing'),
    ->   ('and typesetting industry');
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> CREATE FUNCTION `translit`(`_dn` VARCHAR(30))
    -> RETURNS VARCHAR(30) DETERMINISTIC
    -> RETURN REVERSE(`_dn`);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> \! ./myscript.sh
+ mysql -u root -p -s
Enter password: 
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy NULL
text of the printing    NULL
and typesetting industry    NULL
*************** UPDATE ***************
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy ymmud ylpmis si muspI meroL
text of the printing    gnitnirp eht fo txet
and typesetting industry    yrtsudni gnittesepyt dna
mysql>
```

Try [4.6.6 mysql_config_editor — MySQL Configuration Utility](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-config-editor.html) for not exposing sensitive information.